# Use mySql database data into cordova app using websql

Tags: mysql, cordova, mobile, web-sql

I have mySql database for my web application, now that I am building mobile app for it and I want to clone all the data and put them locally inside the app(cordova app using websql). 
I would like some help, anyone please! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use to method 
1- build rest API to get the data from you web application and feed it to the mobile app .
2-use WEBSQL and store all the data on it and bind it to Cordova .
the first solution is better as you mobile app will be update as soon as the website is updated .
you can use json to get data from the website and get it in the mobile app with java script
here is tutorial  and example code to build mobile app with different kind of data storage 
https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-workshop